# Github as artifact repo in mlflow

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow

Can we use github as one of the options in artifact repository in additions to the object storage support.

Github seems to be a natural way to capture changes in code between different runs/experiments, this will also give a way of tying down the revision of code used in a registered model.

Model version --> runs --> github version.  Nothing golden than this.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run an experiment, while the source from which you ran is in GitHub, that commit is tied to the run.

Registering the model with that version will give the git commit with which the model was run and the subsequent registered version. See both images below.

The first shows the run with a git commit; the second shows that model is registered, with a clickable link (LOCAL_REGISTRY) from the registry UI back to the run UI with its git commit.

[image]

[image]